# Add CALayer below UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I got a `UIView` (let's call it superview) which contains another `UIView` (lets call it subview).

I'd like to add a `CALayer` so that it is visible on top of my superview, but under my subview.
In other words, my subview's background should override the layer.

I've had a look at `addLayer:below:` and others, but I'm not sure how to use it.
Thanks.

**EDIT**: My bad, I had another view between superview and subview, and I was messing with it. Thanks guys !

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:CALayer below:subview.layer]
```

Comment: My bad, I had another view between superview and subview, and I was messing with it. This works like a charm. Thanks !

Comment: The answer is not correct enough. You do not need to insert you CALayer.  Because if you add sublayer to your super view, this layer will definitely be under any subview of this superview.

Answer (score 11):

In **Swift**:

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer, below: self.button1.layer)
```

Comment: what if we haven't `self.button1.layer` in `self.view.layer.subalayers`? If you know the answer please let me know

Comment: Let me know @flinth if my comment above helped you to fix your problem and do not forget to put a +1 for this answer.

Comment: unfortunately not. I know these methods. Look at my question please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564635/swift-remove-layer-without-removing-uiview

Comment: @flinth I just answered your question.

Answer (score 5):

A more general solution where you don't have access to the subviews:

```
layer.insertSublayer(sublayer, at: 0)
```